# i want make a drop down menu at which after click list will open rather mouse hover using CSS not using jquery, javascript etc

Tags: php, html, css

i have made my own drop down menu but i want to make that condition to which after clicking mouse it'll show the list rather mouse hover showing so how to do it using `CSS` is there any property that can i use ?? and i don't want to use jquery or JS.

here is my source code:

```
<ul><li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>
    Portfolio
    <ul>
      <li>Web Design</li>
      <li>Web Development</li>
      <li>Illustrations</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Blog</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>


body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 20px 50px 150px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #E3CAA1;
}

ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
ul li ul li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Please don't use javascript and jquery tags if you specifically say you **don't** want to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, CSS doesn't have [**events**](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp) like Javascript does. The closest thing you'll have to this is the :active state:

```
ul:active
{
    //stuff
}
```

However, this will only be applied while the user is ***holding* the mouse button down** on the element. It will not toggle anything.

You need some form of JS in order to do this properly.

Comment: so, i must go for JS??

Comment: @user3518210 If you want the menu to do something onClick, yes, you **must** use Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is check whether the *ul li* is active instead of checking for a hover.
So what you could do is.

```
ul li ul li:active { background: #666; }
ul li:active ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you can use z-index for that matter.

I would put the menu into a div and change the z-index of the div when the event you prefere is triggered (mouse over, on click, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to detect a click action in CSS alone.  You will either have to use JS or settle for hovering to expand it.  As mentioned in other answers, `element:active` will detect if the user is HOLDING THE MOUSE BUTTON DOWN on that element, but that seems... less desirable.